# SQLAlchemy, the count returns a different number than Python's len() function when using the subqueries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Seems like the sqlalchemy's count() function doesn't return the same value as python's len() function, when using the multiple subqueries with a join inside of one of the subqueries. The question is that, I'm doing the subqueries wrong in generally or is there a bug inside of the sqlalchemy or what is going on here? Can the behavior be explained with how SQL is handling the count in this case?

Fully working small demo code below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# creating a DB in memory, is removed when program stops
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
engine.connect()

Base = declarative_base()

# tables
class TableA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    foo = Column(Boolean)

class TableB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_B'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_table_a = Column(Integer)
    bar = Column(Boolean)

# mapping
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s = Session()

# Test records
s.add(TableA(name='test_1', foo=True)) # relevant main
s.add(TableA(name='test_2', foo=True))
s.add(TableA(name='test_3', foo=False))

s.add(TableB(id_table_a=1, bar=False)) # relevant entry 1
s.add(TableB(id_table_a=1, bar=False)) # relevant entry 2
s.add(TableB(id_table_a=2, bar=True))

# sub queries
sub1 = s.query(TableA).filter(TableA.name == 'test_1').subquery()
sub2 = s.query(TableA).join(TableB, TableB.id_table_a == TableA.id).filter(TableB.bar == False).subquery()

sub_q = s.query(TableA).filter(
        TableA.id == sub1.c.id,
        TableA.id == sub2.c.id
    )

sub_count = sub_q.count()
sub_all = sub_q.all()

print "unrelevant count all: " + str(s.query(TableA).count())
print "sql count: " + str(sub_count)
print "python len: " + str(len(sub_all))
print sub_all
print sub_all[0].name
```

Code prints these values:

```
unrelevant count all: 3
sql count: 2
python len: 1
[<__main__.TableA object at 0x0330FC90>]
test_1
```

As you can see the count() returns the value 2, but if i take the all() and then use the pythons len() function will return 1. Count works just fine if I don't join the tableB, but when joined the count just takes the count from the TableB records, if the join condition matches (i.e. the id_table_a == 1 and bar == False).

Same problem occurs at least with Postgres and sqlite.

Comment: Shouldn't you take a look what is **inside** the table?

Comment: can you put up the rest of your code? the part that prints out the numbers?

Comment: The demo code creates all the entries that are in the DB. 6 recods after comment: "# Test records". And prints are in end of the code, there is nothing else to show, this is all that is needed to reproduce the problem